# to create html canvas elements using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas

I want to create some circles in an html canvas using angularJS.
I know how to do the same using javascript but i am new to angularJS and any help is highly appreciated.

Code:

```
<title>Home Page</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

<div  ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
<canvas id="canvas" width="2100" height="900" 
    style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
</div>
<script>

var $scope;
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller("myctrl", function($scope){
var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(500, 500, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 0.2;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
})

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: hi please check blow link : https://github.com/ActivKonnect/angular-circles

also http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/ActivKonnect/angular-circles/blob/master/example/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.. but i was wondering if there is a way to work with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code works. The main problem is that you tried to access your angular app by the wrong variable(`myapp` instead of `app`). Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tazedorubu/edit?html,console,output) that is running your code.

**But** altering the DOM in a controller is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032855/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-idea-to-manipulate-dom-in-controllers). Use a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to access the DOM objects.

I created a simple [example](http://jsbin.com/nefigedaqi/3/edit?html,console,output) with a directive.

```
app.directive('drawCircle', function() {
return {
  scope: {
    x: '@x',
    y: '@y'
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var x = parseInt(scope.x);
    var y = parseInt(scope.y);
    var canvas = element.parent();
    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
});
```

The directive takes two parameters to set the position of the circle in a canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="2100" height="900" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;">
  <draw-circle x="500" y="500"></draw-circle>
  <draw-circle x="200" y="500"></draw-circle>
</canvas>
```

This will draw two circles inside the canvas.
Hope this helps.

Comment: you forgot to include `drawCircle` in `<canvas>` tag.